# Why does Project Compile without Reference to Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework

I have a number of projects in a solution.  One of those projects, call it MyDAL, defines a number of business objects and uses Entity Framework to persist them via

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
```

I just added a new project to the solution and forgot to reference Entity Framework.

`MyContext` is still available!  There is no compile error (I would think I would get a compiler error telling my I'm missing a reference to the assembly that defines DbContext).

I can reference any of my own properties in `MyContext`.  However,

```
using (MyContext ctx = new MyContext())
```

gives a compiler error

> 'MyNs.MyContext': type used in a using statement must be implicitly
>   convertible to 'System.IDisposable'

and

```
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

gives the error

> 'MyNs.MyContext' does not contain a definition for 'SaveChanges' and
>   no extension method 'SaveChanges' accepting a first argument of...

It's almost as if the compiler silently changed

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
```

to

```
public class MyContext : object
```

I know how to resolve the error (add the missing reference), but I'm curious as to why the code compiled in the first place before I started referencing methods and interfaces of DbContext.

Comment: Without the reference, it would be interesting to see where you end up when you do _Go to Declaration_ on the DbContext.